# Matlab: reading from a .csv file

Tags: matlab

I am trying to import some data from a .csv file, I have search for solutions but no one seems to solve my problem. My .csv is just one column of numbers, but when I try to read it with csvread('myfile.csv') it says that it cannot convert from string. When I double click on the .csv file in matlab I can see that every number from the .csv has this aspect:

"996.47"

So every number is between double commas, and whatever I do I can not get just the number between them. I am trying also opening the file and with textscan but I find no way. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: A sample of at least a small subset of your actual file would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this workaround:

```
V = dlmread('myfile.csv','"');
v = V(:,2)
```

According to your description you have one column of values formatted like "996.47". The first line creates a matrix where columns are delimited by '"' - you get three columns where the middle one is filled with your values. The second line extracts the middle column.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am very new in matlab and I was getting crazy =) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

what about using

```
importdata('yourfile.csv')
```

It should work if you are only interested in data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more generic solution that doesn't need to deal with indexing, you can use MATLAB's built-in function [importdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html).

```
x = importdata('yourfile.csv'); % reads in the file as text surrounded by double quotes
x = cellfun(@str2num,strrep(v,'"','')); % removes the double quotes and changes text to numbers
```